# How do I select a field from the result of a select?

Tags: mysql

I have a working query as follows

```
SELECT r.realname contractor_name, u.uid contractor_uid, ...
```

How can I select just contractor_uid from this result?  I have tried

```
select contractor_uid from (SELECT r.realname contractor_name, u.uid contractor_uid...)
```

But I get the error message

> Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a dummy name after the sub query, i.e.:

```
select contractor_uid from (SELECT r.realname contractor_name, u.uid contractor_uid...) t;
```